# Handling complicated directory structure with python imports

Tags: python

I've worked on several medium-sized python applications to date, and every time it seems like I cobble together a terrible system of imports from tangential Stack Overflow answers and half-understood blog posts.  It's ugly and hard to maintain and ultimately very unsatisfying.  With this question I attempt to put all that behind me.

Say I have a python application split into the following files:

```
app.py
constants.py
ui/window.py
web/connection.py
```

With the following include requirements:

- `app.py` needs to include `window.py` and `connection.py`
- `window.py` needs to include `constants.py` and `connection.py`
- `connection.py` needs to include `constants.py`

`app.py` is the starting point for the application, but `window.py` and `connection.py` are also invokable from the command line to test basic functionality (ideally from within their respective folders).

What combination of `__init__.py` files, carefully crafted import statements and wacky python path magic will allow me to achieve this structure?

Thanks very much,

--Dan

Comment: If it is complicated (even for yourself, the author of the code), maybe the structure isn't a good idea.

Comment: While this example is a bit contrived, the idea of writing a real-world project across tens of files without a robust directory structure is just silly.  In my mind, the purpose of directories is to organize the code, and a large, complicated project with many components is going to take a large, complicated directory.

Comment: A large project may be complex, but doesn't need to be complicated. And IMHO there is never a call for a complicated directory structure. A nested one yes, a vast one yes, but complicated? No.

Comment: Perhaps complicated was the wrong term.  I suppose what I really meant was non-trivial, with components separated rather than everything sitting in the same folder.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look at some complex stdlib and third-party packages, applications, or hybrids to see how they organize their code.

Comment: People getting too hung up on the word 'complicated' -- the directory structure in the example in the post is perfectly reasonable: real-world applications are structured like that in the modern era. The question is reasonable; there is no need to be pedantic at SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really helps if, instead of thinking in terms of "file structure" first and then trying to figure out the packages, you design things in terms of packages, and then lay out your file structure to implement those packages.

But if you want to know how to hack up what you already have: If you put this at the top level (that is, in one of the paths on your `sys.path`), and create files names `ui/__init__.py` and `web/__init__.py`, then:

- `app.py` can be run as a script.
- `app.py` can be run with `-m app`.
- `app.py` can be imported with `import app`.
- `window.py` cannot be run directly.
- `window.py` can be run with `-m ui.window`.
- `window.py` can be imported with `import ui.window`.
- `connection.py` cannot be run directly.
- `connection.py` can be run with `-m web.connection`.
- `connection.py` can be imported with `import web.connection`.

No wacky path magic is needed; you just need the top level (with `app.py`, `constants.py`, `ui`, and `web`) to be on your `sys.path`—which it automatically is when you run with that directory as your working directory, or install everything directly into `site-packages`, or install it as an egg, etc.

That's as close as you're going to get to what you want. You do ever want to run code with a package directory as your current working directory or otherwise on `sys.path`, so don't even try. If you think you need that, what you *probably* want is to separate the runnable code out into a script that you can put at the top level, or somewhere entirely separate. (For example, look at `pip` or `ipython`, which installs scripts into somewhere on your system `$PATH` that do nothing but import some module and run a function.)

The only other thing you might want to consider is putting all of this into a package, say, `myapp`. You do that by adding a top-level `__init__.py`, and then running from the *parent* directory, and adding `myapp.` to the start of all your `import`and `-m` statements. That means you can no longer run `app.py` as a script either, so again you will need to split the script code out into a separate file from the module that does all the work.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  Next time I'll try to think about my packages before I start writing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that structure with just a small modification: add empty `__init__.py` files to the `ui/` and `web/` directory. Then, where you would have done `import window`, do either `import ui.window`, or `from ui import window`. Similarly, change `import connection` to `import web.connection` or `from web import connection`.

Rationale: Python doesn't work so much with *directories* as it does with *packages*, which are directories with an `__init__.py` in them. By changing `ui` and `web` to be packages, you don't have to do any particular Python path magic to work with them, and you get the benefit of adding some structure to your modules and imports. That will become particularly important if you start having modules with the same name in different directories (e.g. a `util.py` in both the `ui` and `web` directories; not necessarily the cleanest design but you get the idea).

If you invoke window.py or connection.py directly to test them, you need to add the top-level directory to your PYTHONPATH for things to still work – but there is a subtle additional wrinkle. When you run this from the top-level directory:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD python web/connection.py
```

you now have both the top-level directory on your module path AND the `web/` directory. This can cause certain relative imports to do unexpected things.

Another way is to use Python's `-m` option from the top-level directory:

```
python -m web.foo
```

I know many folks like to nail their tests right into the modules like this, but I should also note that there are other ways to structure your tests, particularly with an updated `unittest` library and tools like `nosetests`, that will make it a little bit easier to run your tests as your project gets larger. See the skeleton here for a reasonable example:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html